# saving Google places information for better user experience and performance

Tags: google-maps, caching, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

My friend and I are building a standard coffee shop finder app to explore the google places and maps api.

We want to know if we can save google data (just like the name, placeID, lat, long, and maybe type) to user's devices so that our users could see these places - their favourites - as markers on the map, without needing to be connected to the internet.

We are thinking that we could save this information to core-data on the user's device and save just the placeIDs on our server (connected to the users profile) so as not to break Google's caching rules. We are wondering if this would in fact infringe on Google's rules. Any help or insight would be appreciated as Google's documentation on this area is a bit ambiguous.

Also if possible we would like to save some information other then the place IDs to our server. So we are wondering if a business name retrieved from Google's web service api is considered Google's property or is that something we could store on our server? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caching policy is set in section 10.5 d of Google Maps API Terms of Service. You can temporarily save the data for the purpose of improving the performance:

> **No caching or storage.** You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>
> - is temporary (and in no event more than **30 calendar days**);
> - is secure;
> - does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
> - does not modify attribution in any way.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5

Please also note that place ID is exempt from this rule and you can store place IDs without any restrictions. This is documented here:

https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#save-id

Hope this clarifies your doubts.